# re: SOAP Error on Magento 1.9.3.8 -

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

Could really use some help...

Trying to connect to SOAP on Magento 1.9.3.8 - can't get it to work on production site, so testing with a fresh install
I'm getting the exact same errors...

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from http://127.0.0.1/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1
Premature end of data in tag html line 1
If I use our website address instead of 127.0.0.1, I get fatal error "document is empty".

If I access via web http:// or https:// and use our web address, it appears to report the complete xml information fine

I've added our i.p. addresses to hosts file and to hosts allow files

I've tried running secure with everything, then unsecure with everything,

I've increased the default socket timeout to 300

I've tried with default admin routing, and custom also admin routing

If I run PHP info, It shows Soap enabled... I've also checked soap with curl...

I've experimented with the use http settings in Magento... seems to be no difference...

But I still can't get the soap functionality to work...

Am I missing something?...Does anybody have any pointers...

Any help much appreciated... Thank You, Bud